# Is there a way to reference fonts in Component meta data, like styleUrls?

Tags: fonts, angular

I am using third party css from bower in my angular 2 component. I am using the ComponentMetaData `styleUrls` to reference this css file. However it uses font files as well, since it is a icon library.

Is there a way to reference font-files in a similar way we do with the css? Or how would be the best way to include the fonts to the scope of the component like we do with `styleUrls`?

Comment: Can't you just add them to the CSS?

Comment: As @GünterZöchbauer said, you can use [`@font-face`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp) in css file you would include in `styleUrls`

Comment: indeed it was that simple. @font-face worked perfectly! Thanks guys!